# scrapy project middleware -TypeError: process_start_requests() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, scrapy

As soon as I uncomment the project middleware in settings I get an error

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapyspider.middlewares.ScrapySpiderProjectMiddleware': 543,
}
```

Here is my spider

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class DomainLinks(Item):
    links = Field()

class ScrapyProject(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'scrapyspider'

    #allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_links', follow=True),)

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        self.parse_links(response)

    def parse_links(self, response):
        item = DomainLinks()
        item['links'] = []

        links = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),deny = ()).extract_links(response)

        for link in links:  
            if link.url not in item['links']:
                item['links'].append(link.url)

        return item
```

Here is some text extracted from the project middleware file. process_spider_output is where I filtered internal links, and calling process_start_requests causes an error.

```
def process_spider_output(response, result, spider):
    # Called with the results returned from the Spider, after
    # it has processed the response.

    domain = response.url.strip("http://","").strip("https://","").strip("www.").strip("ww2.").split("/")[0]

    filtered_result = []
    for i in result:
        if domain in i:
            filtered_result.append(i)


    # Must return an iterable of Request, dict or Item objects.
    for i in filtered_result:
       yield i

def process_start_requests(start_requests, spider):
    # Called with the start requests of the spider, and works
    # similarly to the process_spider_output() method, except
    # that it doesn’t have a response associated.

    # Must return only requests (not items).
    for r in start_requests:
        yield r
```

Traceback

```
2017-05-01 12:30:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapyproject.middlewares.scrapyprojectSpiderMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-05-01 12:30:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-05-01 12:30:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2017-05-01 12:30:55 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2017-05-01 12:30:55 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1301, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 74, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
TypeError: process_start_requests() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I am trying to filtered links so only internal links are followed/extracted

The scrapy documentation isn't very clear..

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, just uncomment the other middleware class methods " # Not all methods need to be defined. If a method is not defined,
    # scrapy acts as if the spider middleware does not modify the
    # passed objects.
"

Comment: or add self to the class methods process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As all scrapy middlewares that I have seen are inside of classes, I suspect the `self` parameter is missing:

```
def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
    # ...

def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
    # ...
```

Hope this helps. If not please post the complete middleware file.